# Beta regression for ratio of counts

Tags: mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model, beta-regression

I have a question about whether it is appropriate to use beta regression when the proportion is formed as a ratio of counts. I have seen information suggesting it is fine and others pointing out that the distribution of the ratio is discrete. Any ideas as to which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be worth trying, especially if the counts are rather large so that you get something close to continuous.

But if both counts are rather low (possibly even including zeros) then a binomial model would be most natural.

Finally if the main response is a rather low count and the denominator ("exposure") is rather large then a Poisson model with offset would be the classic choice.